# Retrofit2 with Kotlin null responses

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Attempting to make an api call to https://martialwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/PostModel which just returns a simple Json object with some junk data. I am retrieving a list the with correct number of entries but all but the ID field is blank. Why are all the fields but the ID blank.

Response

```
0 = {PostModel@5599} "PostModel(ID=1, title=null, dataType=0, content=null)"
1 = {PostModel@5600} "PostModel(ID=2, title=null, dataType=0, content=null)"
2 = {PostModel@5601} "PostModel(ID=3, title=null, dataType=0, content=null)"
3 = {PostModel@5602} "PostModel(ID=4, title=null, dataType=0, content=null)"
```

Client Call

```
private fun apiCall() {
    val client = RetrofitClientKotlin.create()
    client.getPopularPosts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                var postResponse: List<PostModel> = it
                adapter.setPosts(postResponse)
            },{
                it.printStackTrace()
            })

}
```

Client

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static final String baseURL = "https://martialwebapi.azurewebsites.net";

    private static Retrofit getClient(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static ApiService getApiService(){
        return getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

Api Interface

```
interface MartialApiService {
    @GET("/api/PostModel")
    fun getPopularPosts(): Observable<List<PostModel>>
}
```

Model

```
data class PostModel(val ID: Int, val title: String, val dataType: Int, val content: String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml use camelcase Title, Content, etc.., and you're using lowercase title, content, etc...
With Gson you may add `@SerializedName` annotation when your local variables don't match xml node names:

```
data class PostModel(
    @SerializedName("ID") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("Title") val title: String, 
    @SerializedName("DataType") val dataType: Int, 
    @SerializedName("Content") val content: String
)
```

Comment: This worked! I tend to switch coding styles between C# and Android. First time I was actually tripped up by it

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any question here but answear would probably be
Use `retrofit2.Response` to avoid null pointer exeption

```
interface MartialApiService {
    @GET("/api/PostModel")
    fun getPopularPosts(): Observable<Response<List<PostModel>>>
}
```

And check if response isSuccessful and body not null

Comment: The question was why my objects had null for every field expect ID, Samuel answered the question. It was because the field names were using difficult capitalization styles.

Comment: @Ubarjohade ok, but please use retrofit2.Response for better response handle.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use simple-xml.

> implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:$retrofitVersion"

and change your factory.

```
private static Retrofit getClient(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(
        SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict(
            new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy() // important part!
          )
                .build();
    }
```

in your datamodel set a @root to false

```
@Root(strict = false)
data class PostModel(val ID: Int, val title: String, val dataType: Int, val content: String)
```

It should works.

Comment: Hmm still gives a bunch of nulls with this method. Why use a XML Converter? When I send the GET using Postman it looks as if the response is in Json

Comment: https://martialwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/PostModel  here it looks a xml response: